# Dask-Yarn: Batch Inferencing Taking Too Long?

Tags: python, dask, distributed-computing, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

**Problem**

I'm trying to perform some batch model inferencing using dask-yarn, following this [documentation](https://examples.dask.org/machine-learning/torch-prediction.html) as an example.

The full data I'm working with is about 9M rows (not too overly big), where each row corresponds to model features. There are 2 models - one using Bert and the other using XgBoost so I need to make 2 passes through the data.

I tested this on some sample data (1000 rows) and using just 10 dask workers, and it seemed to run just fine. But once I scale the number of dask workers to 200 with 1 cpu each, and run against the whole dataset, it becomes slower than anticipated.

I'm not the most experienced with Dask, so would appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

**Example Code**

```
cluster = YarnCluster(environment='uq_component_dask.tar.gz', 
                      worker_vcores=1, 
                      worker_memory="8GiB",
                      worker_env={"TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM": "True"}
                     )
client = Client(cluster)
cluster.scale(200)

model_xgb, model_bert, tokenizer = model.load_models()
d_bert_model = dask.delayed(model_bert)
d_xgb_model = dask.delayed(model_xgb)

files = ['s3://ch-ml-data/uq_component_count/dataset_v4/' + str(i) for i in range(1,31)]
ddf = dd.read_parquet(files)
ddf = ddf.persist()
ddf = ddf.dropna(subset=['content'])
ddf = ddf.dropna(subset=['question_id'])
ddf = ddf.dropna(subset=['subject'])
ddf = ddf.repartition(partition_size="100MB")
ddf = ddf.persist()
ddf['bert_regression_prediction_decimal'] = ddf.content.apply(
    bert_predict,
    model=d_bert_model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    meta=('content', 'object')
)
ddf['features'] = ddf.apply(
    feature_preprocessing,
    axis=1
)
ddf['ml_prediction'] = ddf.features.apply(
    xgb_predict,
    model=d_xgb_model,
    meta=('features', 'object')
)
ddf = ddf.persist()
ddf['version'] = '1.0.3'
ddf = ddf[ddf.ml_prediction!=0]
ddf = ddf[['question_id', 'subject', 'version', 'ml_prediction']]
df = ddf.compute()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I tested this on some sample data (1000 rows) and using just 10 dask workers, and it seemed to run just fine. But once I scale the number of dask workers to 200 with 1 cpu each, and run against the whole dataset, it becomes slower than anticipated.

One reason could be that some parts of the code are not scaling well with the heterogeneity in data. For example, imagine there is a one-hot-encoding step that runs fine on 1000 rows, but as the number of rows increases, the number of one-hot-encoded columns might increase, slowing down some parts of the computations. Similar bottlenecks could arise if data shuffling is needed at some point.